# What is the purpose of the string "- 4/24" from a record that holds a date?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I have an already generated script that uses the following code: `ORDER BY TO_CHAR((A.VERIFIED_DTTM - 4/24),'YYYY-MM-DD')`. The output of `A.VERIFIED_DTTM` is a simple date eg: `09-SEP-19`.

I was my understanding that `4/24` is the same as saying 4 hours. I have tried removing this string from my query and received radically different results (not just sorting or ordering).

In another area of the script, I have a code that makes excellent sense (`A.VERIFIED_DTTM >= sysdate - 30`). This I understand.

Can anyone explain what is actually happening with this query line?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is subtracting 4 hours and converting the date value to a string in the format of YYYY-MM-DD.  This is probably a timezone adjustment.

To be honest, I'm not sure why it doesn't just use:

```
ORDER BY A.VERIFIED_DTTM
```

Removing it should not radically change the results.

Comment: Nor I. I'm curious though how it removes 4 hours though when hours aren't stored in the original record. And strangely enough, as I said, the records are radically different (not just ordered differently) without it.

Comment: @DavidTurner . . . In Oracle, `date`s have a time component, whether you see it or not.  Unfortunately, the standard output generally hides the time.

Comment: WOW. That's news. Now it makes a little more sense. Like I said, I'm looking at this output in dbeaver and sql developer and seeing just a date. If there is a hidden time stamp, then it would make excellent sense! Thank you for that nugget!